# How do I open USER Temp Folder, and not Windows TEMP

Tags: c#, forms

So I made this script so when the user clicks on a button it launches the TEMP folder. Now the problem is that it's the Windows TEMP and not users TEMP. I tried googling some solutions but I don't know the exact keyword.

```
private void button37_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\temp");
    }
```

I tried something like this "C:/Users/%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Temp". 
But that didn't work. Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Replace `C:\temp` with a call to [Path.GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=netframework-4.7.20), `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath());`

Comment: Thanks! I also just found the documentation on this right when you replied!

Comment: hi, There are more than one ways to achieve this. I add an answer explaining why your first attempt did not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%USERPROFILE%` expands to "C:\Users\yourusername", so you could try

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Temp");
```

Or use the call [System.IO.Path.GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=netframework-4.7.2) which

> checks for the existence of environment variables in the following order and uses the first path found:
>
> The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
>
> The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
>
> The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
>
> The Windows directory.